# If $x*y$ is the operation $x*y = xy/(x+y+1)$, then how does $x*y*z = xyz(x+y+1)/(x+y+z+xy+xz+1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$$x*y = \frac{xy}{x+y+1}$$

What I got was,

$$x*(y*z) = x* \frac{yz}{y+z+1} =x\frac{\frac{yz}{y+z+1}}{x+\frac{yz}{y+z+1}+1}$$

The book's answer is

$$x*(y*z) = x*\frac{yz}{y+z+1} = \frac{xyz(y+z+1)}{x+y+z+xy+xz+1}$$

Comment: I think the book is wrong. It should be $\frac{xyz}{x+y+z+xy+xz+yz+1}$, which is what you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go on from where you stopped:
$$
\frac{x\dfrac{yz}{y+z+1}}{x+\dfrac{yz}{y+z+1}+1}=
\frac{\dfrac{xyz}{y+z+1}}{\dfrac{(x+1)(y+z+1)+yz}{y+z+1}}=
\frac{xyz}{(x+1)(y+z+1)+yz}
$$
Thus you get
$$
x*(y*z)=\frac{xyz}{x+y+z+xy+yz+zx+1}
$$
The book's answer is wrong. Set $x=y=1$. Then
$$
y*z=\frac{1}{3}
$$
and so
$$
x*(y*z)=1*\frac{1}{3}=\frac{\dfrac{1}{3}}{1+\dfrac{1}{3}+1}=\frac{1}{7}
$$
The book's formula would give $1/2$, while
$$
\frac{xyz}{x+y+z+xy+yz+zx+1}=\frac{1}{7}
$$
as expected.

Answer (score 0):

$x*y=\frac{xy}{x+y+1}$

We put $  b=x*y=\frac{xy}{x+y+1}. $

$b*z=\frac{bz}{b+z+1}=\frac{\frac{xy}{x+y+1}z}{\frac{xy}{x+y+1}+z+1}$

$x*y*z=\frac{zxy}{xy+xz+yz+z+x+y+1}$

So: the book is wrong